# Check if filename from directory exists as a value in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a bunch of .png's in a directory that are named the same as the values in the database. I would like to do a check if the filename (without '.png') exists in the database or not.

At the moment I am using this code to display the flags those are in the database

```
<?php
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT `country` FROM `countries`");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {;
?>
  <img src="images/countries/<?php echo $row['country']?>.png" />
<?php }; ?>
```

Since there are only 3 countries in the column it's displayed as:
[image]

I would like to display the flags that are not in the database as well, but then in greyscale.

I came up wit this code to get all the flags from the directory

```
<?php
  $directory = "images/countries/";
  $images = glob($directory . "*.png");

  foreach($images as $image)
  {
    echo '<image src="'.$image.'" class="flaginactive"/>'; //show all flags as inactive
    echo basename($image, '.png'); //get file name with .png
  }
?>
```

**But somehow I am stuck and clueless how I could get them both in an if statement.**

Can someone advise me how I can solve this the best way. I am aware I am using the old mySQL functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this. I will relate one.

First load the names in the database in to an array. Then check the existence of the enumerated file names of the directory in the array to decide the class of the element.

Elements are shown inactive if a file in the directory is not found in the database.

```
<?php

  $directory = "images/countries/";

  //Lets save all the file names in the database to an array 
  $dbImages = array();

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT `country` FROM `countries`");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

     array_push($dbImages, $directory . $row['country'] . '.png'); 

  }



  //Lets go through all the files in the directory and see if they are in the $dbImages array    
  $images = glob($directory . "*.png");

  foreach($images as $image)
  {
    //Decide the class attribute based on the existence of the file name in $dbImages array

    if (in_array($image, $dbImages))
       $classAttribute = '';
    else
       $classAttribute = 'class="flaginactive"' 

    echo '<image src="'.$image.'" ' . $classAttribute . ' />'; 

  }


?>
```

Comment: @Charlie H, first of all thank you for your help! I really really appreciate how you broke it down for me step by step with the comments :)! The code broke my page but it finally worked when I added a semicolon to the else statement.

Comment: Your first code snip breaks php segments too much apart in my opinion. Please try to do things plain as possible. Great if my answer was of some use for you.

Comment: Yeah I figured out indeed! Do you know how I could add the value from the database to the alt="" of the image as well?

Comment: Here is one way to do it. Add the image names and values from the database to the array in the following format [image1, value, image2, value2, image3, value3]. Now in your second loop (forEach) just get your value if you have the image in the database like this `$value = $dbImages[array_search($image, $dbImages) + 1]`. I hope you understand what goes on here. I will write an answer if you post another question and notify me here.

Comment: Hi Charlie H, I just noticed your answer. Thanks a lot! I figured it out! ^^

Answer (score -1):

You can file_exists() function like this

```
<?php
         $directory = "images/countries/";
         $images = glob($directory . "*.png");

       foreach($images as $image)
       {
          if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $directory . $image . '.png')) //Files exists goes here
         {
            echo '<image src="'.$image.'" class="flaginactive"/>';            //show all flags as inactive
            echo basename($image, '.png'); //get file name with .png
           }
       }
?>
```